# how to convert an user number in days or hours or seconds swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am new in Swift UI, I am trying to convert a value what I get from a textfiled and picker to convert that in days, minutes or seconds, this is from the tutorial 100 days with swiftUI i am lost because I dont understand how do the operations if someone can help me and explain me a little the code please, thank you.

this is my code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var convertir  = 2
    let tipConverciones = ["segundos","minutos","horas","dias"]
    @State private var convertirselection  = 2
    let convertirA = ["segundos","minutos","horas","dias"]
    @State var cantidadconvertir = ""

    var convertidormetodo: Double{
        //Funcion que calcula el total de personas
        let conteocantidad = Double(cantidadconvertir) ?? 0
        let convertirSeleccion = (convertirA)



        return 0
    }

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{
        Form {
        Section (header: Text("Convertir")) {

        Picker   ("Convertir de", selection: $convertir){
            ForEach(0 ..< tipConverciones.count){
                Text("\(self.tipConverciones[$0])")
            }//ForEach
        }//Picker
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        }//Seccion3

            Section (header: Text("Ingresar Cantidad a convertir"))  {
                  TextField("Ingresa la cuentidad", text: $cantidadconvertir)
                     .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            }//seccion5

            Section (header: Text("Convertir a")) {

            Picker   ("Convertir de", selection: $convertir){
                ForEach(0 ..< tipConverciones.count){
                    Text("\(self.tipConverciones[$0])")
                }//ForEach
            }//Picker
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            }//Seccion4


            Section{//seccion 4
                            Text("La cantidad convertida es: \(convertidormetodo)")
                       }//seccion 4
            }//Form
            .navigationBarTitle("Convertidor SwiftUI")
        }//Navigation View
    }//body
}//view

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

an example of a user input and the desired output would help. But I think what you're looking for is either the dateFormatter or numberFormatter:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter

Comment: yes I am serching how create the operations in a method, I am going to read the information that you sharme